# with SQL i am wanting to report on a persons last time they logged in

Tags: sql

i have the below script that i use to find users log in log out sessions. Can this be modified to show who has NOT logged in since say 2 months? I just can't figure this one out

```
select
    A.USERNAME, P.NAME, L.LOGINSESSIONID, L.AGENTID, L.LOGINID, L.STATE,
    L.CREATED, L.TERMINATED, (L.TERMINATED_TS - L.CREATED_TS) AS Duration  
from
    GIDB_G_LOGIN_SESSION_V L,
    GIDB_GC_AGENT A,
    GIDB_GC_PLACE P 
WHERE
    (L.CREATED >= to_date ('20/09/2016' , 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
    and
    (L.CREATED < to_date ('22/09/2016' , 'DD/MM/YYYY')) 
    AND
    (L.AGENTID = A.ID) 
    AND
    (L.PLACEID = P.ID) 
    --AND A.USERNAME IN ('13866')`
```

Comment: mysql or sql server

Comment: TO_DATE is Oracle syntax... OP is very confused

Comment: In addition, your joining syntax was replaced nearly 10 years ago. You might want to investigate **EXPLICIT JOINS**

Comment: @JohnHC . . . `TO_DATE()` can also be used in Postgres (and hence in many derived databases) and Teradata.  The OP managed to find two databases that don't support it.  I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Cool, learned a new thing (I've never used PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle version (based on your existing to_date() function):

```
select A.USERNAME, P.NAME, max(L.CREATED) as LAST_LOGIN
from GIDB_G_LOGIN_SESSION_V L
inner join GIDB_GC_AGENT A
  on A.ID = L.AGENTID
inner join GIDB_GC_PLACE P 
  on P.ID = L.PLACEID
where not exists 
    (select X.AGENT_ID
     from GIDB_G_LOGIN_SESSION_V X
     where X.CREATED >= add_months(trunc(sysdate),-2)
     and X.AGENTID = L.AGENTID)
group by A.USERNAME, P.NAME
```

SQL Server:

```
select A.USERNAME, P.NAME, max(L.CREATED) as LAST_LOGIN
from GIDB_G_LOGIN_SESSION_V L
inner join GIDB_GC_AGENT A
  on A.ID = L.AGENTID
inner join GIDB_GC_PLACE P 
  on P.ID = L.PLACEID
left join GIDB_G_LOGIN_SESSION_V X
  on X.AGENTID = L.AGENTID
  and X.CREATED >= dateadd(mm,-2,getdate())
where X.AGENTID is null
group by A.USERNAME, P.NAME
```

MySQL:

```
select A.USERNAME, P.NAME, max(L.CREATED) as LAST_LOGIN
from GIDB_G_LOGIN_SESSION_V L
inner join GIDB_GC_AGENT A
  on A.ID = L.AGENTID
inner join GIDB_GC_PLACE P 
  on P.ID = L.PLACEID
left join GIDB_G_LOGIN_SESSION_V X
  on X.AGENTID = L.AGENTID
  and X.CREATED >= date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)
where X.AGENTID is null
group by A.USERNAME, P.NAME
```

Comment: brilliant ! thank you so much JohnHC, it works perfectly :-) i could not figure out the 'where not exists' been at this for days